# etree insert node attribute into filtered children

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am processing an xml file. I want to create an output as a list of tuples to mass insert into a database.

the issue I cannot seem to achieve is inserting an @id from the node into selected attributes from the child nodes.

This is my example doc. Note in my real file there are many more attributes in each level that need to be filtered out. I created this XML file as a more usable sample.

```
doc = """
<region id="5153419" name="North Shore" date="2019-02-15T00:00:00" >
  <shire abbrevname="Manly Council" code="20019" website="http://" >
  <location id="5178566" site="1" division="Dee Why" staff="3" >
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-75-4" rating="Mature (18+)" title="110 Per¢" author="Tony Consiglio"/>
    <reference isbn="978-1-60309-2395" rating="Mature (16+)" title="American Elf 1999" author="James Kochalka" />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-37-2" rating="Young Adult (13+)" title="The Barefoot Serpent (softcover)" author="Scott Morse" />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-56-3" rating="Mature (16+)" title="Bighead" author="Jeffrey Brown"  />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-19-8" rating="Mature (18+)" title="Box Office Poison" author="Alex Robinson"  />
  </location>
  <location id="5178568" site="2" division="Brookvale" staff="5">
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-37-2" rating="Young Adult (13+)" title="The Barefoot Serpent (softcover)" author="Scott Morse"/>
    <reference isbn="978-1-936561-69-8" rating="Adults Only (18+)" title="Chester 5000 (Book 2)" author="Isabelle George" />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-81-5" rating="Young Adult (13+)" title="Cry Yourself to Sleep" author="Jeremy Tinder" />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-75-4" rating="Mature (18+)" title="110 Per¢" author="Tony Consiglio" />
    <reference isbn="978-1-891830-77-8" rating="Mature (16+)" title="Every Girl is the End of the World for Me" author="Jeffrey Brown" />
    <reference isbn="978-0-9585783-4-9" rating="Mature (18+)" title="From Hell" author="Alan Moore and Eddie Campbell" />
  </location> 
  </shire>
</region>
"""
```

My desired output would be

(location id, isbn, title)

```
[(5153419, 978-1-891830-75-4,110 Per¢),(5153419, 978-1-60309-2395, American Elf 1999).......(5178568,978-0-9585783-4-9,From Hell)]
```

Tried this many ways getiterator, findall. Just can't find a way to achieve it.

```
filter_reference = ['isbn', 'title']
output_list = []
for child in tree.findall('.//reference'):
    for k,v in child.items():
        if k in filter_reference:
            output_list.append(v)
```

Comment: You want location id or region id? first it's region id then it became second location id.

Comment: its location id then isbn then title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through childs and get what attribute you need:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

doc = """
your doc
"""
root = et.fromstring(doc)
result = []

for shire in root:
    for location in shire:
        location_id = location.attrib.get('id')
        for reference in location:
            list_of_attribs = [reference.attrib.get(x) for x in filter_reference]
            result.append((location_id, list_of_attribs))

print(result) # [('5178566', '978-1-891830-75-4', '110 Per¢'), ('5178566', '978-1-60309-2395', 'American Elf 1999'), ('5178566', '978-1-891830-37-2', 'The Barefoot Serpent (softcover)'), ('5178566', '978-1-891830-56-3', 'Bighead'), ('5178566', '978-1-891830-19-8', 'Box Office Poison'), ('5178568', '978-1-891830-37-2', 'The Barefoot Serpent (softcover)'), ('5178568', '978-1-936561-69-8', 'Chester 5000 (Book 2)'), ('5178568', '978-1-891830-81-5', 'Cry Yourself to Sleep'), ('5178568', '978-1-891830-75-4', '110 Per¢'), ('5178568', '978-1-891830-77-8', 'Every Girl is the End of the World for Me'), ('5178568', '978-0-9585783-4-9', 'From Hell')]
```

Comment: I can't directly reference each attribute as in your example. In reality, there is 25 attributes in location and I need 15 of them. Which is where the issue really occurs. Because I need to use the list as in my example to filter out the attributes and then add them to the output.

Comment: @sayth I can't understand what is your problem exactly if you want some of attributes just get them and leave the others , you can loop through your filtered list and get those attributes.

Comment: Creating the second looping of the list seems to have made it harder. I had achieved it similar to your answer (with limited attributes) but looping the filtered list just wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: @sayth check out new answer , just get filtered attribs and append them to result list.